# Updating Database with DataGrid C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagrid

I have a datagrid setup in my windows form in Visual Studio. The datagrid is updated from the textboxes but I can't get it to edit the values held in the database.

This is the code I am using:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=admin";
        string Query = "UPDATE database.taxi SET PickupLocation='" + txtPickupLocation.Text + "',PickupArea='" + comboBxPickupArea.Text + "',PickupTime='" + dateTimePickup.Text + "',DestinationLocation'" + txtDestinationLocation.Text + "',DestinationArea='" + comboBxDestinationArea.Text + "',Name'" + txtCustomerName.Text + "',Address='" + txtCustomerAddress.Text + "',Tour='" + comboBxTour.Text + "',VehicleRegistration='" + txtvehicleregistration.Text + "' ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Entry has been updated");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {



            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But I get the error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your SQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"DestinationLocation'"......... "

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to use `=` after your `DestinationLocation` and `Name`

Change your

```
DestinationLocation'" + txtDestinationLocation.Text
```

and

```
Name'" + txtCustomerName.Text + "'
```

to

```
DestinationLocation = '" + txtDestinationLocation.Text
```

and

```
Name = '" + txtCustomerName.Text + "'
```

But please don't use string concatenation in your sql queries. Use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also you don't need to use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since your query doesn't return anything. Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

As a full code;

```
string Query = "UPDATE database.taxi SET PickupLocation=@PickupLocation, PickupArea=@PickupArea, PickupTime=@PickupTime, DestinationLocation=@DestinationLocation,
                DestinationArea=@DestinationArea, Name=@Name, Address@Address, Tour=@Tour, VehicleRegistration=@VehicleRegistration";
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickupLocation", txtPickupLocation.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickupArea", comboBxPickupArea.Text);
....
....
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That is excellent, thank you so much for your help. Just one more thing, it is updating all the entries in the database now. How can I make it so it only updates the one row?

Comment: @user3080562 You are quite welcome. Please consider to accept as an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work If you only update one row, you should consider to use `WHERE` statement in your `UPDATE` query. For example, `...WHERE Name = "blabla"` , updates your row only where your row `Name` is `blabla`

Answer (score 1):

You need an equals sign after `DestinationLocation` in your SQL.

Incidentally, you probably don't want to use `ExecuteReader`, since you're not returning any values (and aren't interested in any.) Try `ExecuteNonQuery`.

ETA:  and Soner Gönül is absolutely right about the need for parameterized queries rather than string concatenation!

Finally, I assume that you aren't going to hard-code your connection string in your final version?

Comment: Beat me with 5 seconds `:)`